# Как прослушивать изменения firestore в реальном времени?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase, firestore

Я реализую чат приложение , для этого мне нужно обрабатывать сообщения сразу при отправке , но я сталкиваюсь со следующей проблемой

Вот код слушателя сообщений

```
    private fun listenMessage() {
    database
        .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
        .document(preferenceManager.getString(KEY_USER_ID)!!)
        .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
        .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            if (error != null) {
                return@addSnapshotListener
            } else {
                if (value == null) {
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                } else {

                    for (documentChange in value.documentChanges) {
                        if (documentChange.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                            var doc = documentChange.document
                            if (doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID) == receiverUser.uid) {
                                var text = doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE).toString()
                                var id = doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_ID).toString()
                                var receiverId =
                                    doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID).toString()
                                var date = doc.getTimestamp(KEY_MESSAGE_DATE)!!.toDate()
                                var isChecked = doc.getBoolean(KEY_MESSAGE_ISCHECKED)!!
                                var type = doc.getString(KEY_TYPE_MESSAGE).toString()
                                var message =
                                    Message(text, id, receiverId, date, isChecked, type)
                                if (message !in messages) {
                                    messages.add(message)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    messages.sortBy { it -> it.date }
                    var messages_test = ArrayList(messages)
                    userChatAdpater.updateList(messages_test)
                    if (messages.size != 0) {
                        mBinding.rvUserChat.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size - 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    database
        .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
        .document(receiverUser.uid)
        .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
        .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            if (error != null) {
                return@addSnapshotListener
            } else {
                if (value == null) {
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                } else {
                    for (documentChange in value.documentChanges) {
                        documentChange.document.reference.update(KEY_MESSAGE_ISCHECKED, true)
                        if (documentChange.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                            var doc = documentChange.document
                            if (doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID) == preferenceManager.getString(
                                    KEY_USER_ID
                                )
                            ) {
                                var text = doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE).toString()
                                var id = doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_ID).toString()
                                var receiverId =
                                    doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID).toString()
                                var date = doc.getDate(KEY_MESSAGE_DATE)!!
                                var isChecked = doc.getBoolean(KEY_MESSAGE_ISCHECKED)!!
                                var type = doc.getString(KEY_TYPE_MESSAGE).toString()
                                var message =
                                    Message(text, id, receiverId, date, isChecked, type)
                                if (message !in messages) {
                                    messages.add(message)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    messages.sortBy { it -> it.date }
                    var messages_test = ArrayList(messages)
                    userChatAdpater.updateList(messages_test)
                    if (messages.size != 0) {
                        mBinding.rvUserChat.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size - 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

При попадании на экран чата , все сообщения подгружаются  нормально

```
date -> {Value@24360} "# com.google.firestore.v1.Value@f6d54b4d
timestamp_value {
nanos: 926000000
seconds: 1661083055
}
```

Но при отправке сообщения происходит следующее

```
date -> {Value@24661} "# com.google.firestore.v1.Value@5340a934
map_value {
 fields {
   key: "__type__"
   value {
     string_value: "server_timestamp"
   }
 }
 fields {
   key: "__local_write_time__"
   value {
     timestamp_value {
       nanos: 576000000
       seconds: 1661089684
     }
   }
 }
 }"
```

Из-за этого в `date` записывается `null`
Но я не знаю другого способа реализации прослушивателя сообщений
Время генерируется благодаря `@ServerTimestamp`

Comment: давайте ещё раз уточним, при отправке сообщения и при стартовой подгрузке списка у вас всегда есть время, просто от сервера приходит разный json, правильно?

Comment: да я получаю json по полю "date" , при загрузке сообщений в нем сразу хранятся данные что позволяет мне конвертировать их в объект типа `Date` , при отправке же сообщения я получаю map , который возвращает мне почему то в переменную `null` , скорее всего потому что я использую `getTimestamp` , но я пробовал использовать просто `get` , результат такой же `null`

Comment: я тогда предлагаю сделать что-то типа `var date = doc.getTimestamp(KEY_MESSAGE_DATE)?let{
// обычный режим работы
} ?: run { // тут когда получили от сервера не data}`

Comment: и в map мне кажется не может быть два одинаковых ключа, а у вас там fields два раза повторяется, что именно вы можете получить например через отладчик, то есть апи вам может дать что-то типа `map.get("fields")` где будут ваша модель с двумя вариантами времени?

Comment: проблема заключается в том что ответ который я получаю при отправке , я никак не могу обработать , нет возможности его записать или обработать , я могу лишь увидеть его через отладчик , я могу предположить что при отправке сообщения метка времени еще не успевает сгенерироваться , но с другой стороны срабатывает `addSnapshotListener` в котором должна быть сгенерированная метка

Comment: любой метод доступный для получения данных возвращает `null`

Comment: я уже понял что вы не можете обработать, тут важно понять приходит ли от сервера хоть что-то после отправки? понятно что вы не обрабатываете его как нужно, самый топорный способ - запрашивать после каждой отправки список сообщений заново, но это фигово в плане архитектуры, посему нужно все-таки его как-то ловить

Comment: Я обнаружил `DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior`  Управляет возвращаемым значением для временных меток сервера, которые еще не были установлены в окончательное значение. так говорится в документации , возможно все таки метка не успевает генерироваться , тогда как можно на несколько миллисекунд затормозить процесс?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138674/discussion-between-andrew-and-danil).